# Is it possible to center the contents of a variable width, auto overflow div purely from CSS?

Tags: css

I've read through several similar questions, but none of them apply to this case.

There's a div, which contains cells. Each cell is the same size. The div should be variable width, and allow overflow. There will be more cells that can fit into one row. The problem is, the contents are left-aligned. Please see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gpcpfbmb/

```
<div id="holder">
  <div id="cell">
    <img width="160" height="100" src="http://lorempixel.com/160/100/" /><br />Caption
  </div> <!-- ... etc -->
</div>
```

This could be fixed from JavaScript: write a function which measures the screen width, calculate the number of columns, then set the width of the div to columns * cell width pixels. (E.g., in the example, if you're seeing 3 columns, and the cell width is 170 pixels in this case, 3 * 170 = 510, setting the width to *510px* would give the "perfect" result. However, as soon as the browser window is resized, all the benefits of variable width and auto overflow are lost.)

So: is it possible to have the cells centered, using *only* CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the cell from `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;` and add  `text-align:center;` to the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpcpfbmb/2/